# Archive Records but usable for Marketing Cloud, reporting and support

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, data-storage, archive

We need a solution to archive records (Orders and Order Products) so they will not count towards storage. But still accessible for support agents, reporting and Marketing Cloud.

Do you know of a way?

Answer (score 2):

If by storage you mean "GBs of data stored on SFMC", this should not give you problems, as I am yet to see an account being asked to reduce the data volumes stored. Especially not when they originate from records in Data Extensions.

If you mean Contact count, Orders and Order products will not add to this figure, as they (I assume) don't use Contact Key as primary key, but rather OrderID and OrderItemID.

Hence - no actions should not be needed.

Comment: My concern is about Service Cloud storage, is to high. And I want to move some data from it to reduce the storage, but still be able to use the data in Marketing Cloud and if needed also in Service Cloud (Support agents + reporting)

Comment: You can use [external objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_data_sources.htm&type=5) however this will involve a significant work effort on building a process for moving records from Orders and Order products objects, into these new custom objects. Additionally, external objects are not supported by the connector - so here you will also utilise SFMC API for syncing.